# Django model datas as preset for creating other model

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm actually writing an application for a BioTech laboratory. The idea is to prepare environments with preset list of products.

There is also a need to handle the stock of products.

I tried the following structure but I have no idea how to handle the presets...

```
#models.py
class Products(models.Model):
    nutrients = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    globalQuantity = models.FloatField()
    rcvdate = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    lot = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Environments(models.Model):
    lot = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    initvolume = models.FloatField()
    preparation = ?

class Presets(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    product = models.ForeignKey('products', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.FloatField()
```

The idea is then to populate preset like following :

```
 1. name = preset1 | product = NH4  | quantity = 50
 2. name = preset1 | product = SO4  | quantity = 25
 3. name = preset2 | product = NaCl | quantity = 40
 4. name = preset2 | product = Mn   | quantity = 30
```

Where a "recipe" (like preset1 and preset2) contains different products. It must be dynamic because users needs to be able to add "recipes" if they want.

The problem is : " How to add a preparation to an environment using one preset defined in the class presets ? "

The fields of a table are defined at beginning so how handle preparations which can be different following preset structure ?

Comment: The models you should capitalize the first letter.

Comment: Thanks for the advice =)

Comment: And pay attention to singular/plural...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an extra model: `Recipe`. Always model your db with the things you also talk about, that makes it way easier. Assumption: presets can be reused by many recipes.

```
def Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    presets = models.ManyToManyField(Preset)

def Preset(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quantity = models.FloatField()

def Environment(model.Model):
    etc...
    preparation = ForeignKey(Recipe)
```

Comment: An alternative would be to use a `ManyToMany` with `through` relationship, so that an `environment` links to `presets` _through_ a `recipe`.

Comment: I did it with the 'through' parameter :)
Thank you for your quick answer !